# Apply function to one element only in list or array in Scala

Tags: arrays, list, scala, scala-collections, zipper

For any given list or array, for instance

```
val list = (1 to 3).toList
val array = (1 to 3).toArray
```

and a given function that maps from and onto the collection type, for instance

```
def f(v: Int): Int = v + 10
```

how to apply `f` to the ith element of `list` or `array` so that

```
list.myApply(f, ith = 2)
res: List(1,12,3)
```

and also

```
array.myApply(f, ith = 2)
res: Array(1,12,3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class Seq_[A, Repr, 
    S : ({type L[X] = X => SeqLike[A, Repr]})#L](seq: S) {

  def myApply[B >: A, That](f: A => B, ith: Int)
      (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

---

**Discussion**

A naive approximation:

```
implicit class Seq_[A](seq: Seq[A]) {
  def myApply(f: A => A, ith: Int): Seq[A] =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

Example usage:

```
scala> (1 to 3).toList.myApply(_ + 10, ith = 2)
res: Seq[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)
```

---

Attempted actual solution:

```
implicit class Seq_[A, Repr <: SeqLike[A, Repr]](seq: Repr) {
  def myApply[B >: A, That](f: A => B, ith: Int)
                           (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

Unfortunately, the implicit doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

```
scala> Seq_[Int, List[Int]]((1 to 3).toList).myApply(_ + 10, ith = 2)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)

scala> Seq_[Int, List[Int]]((1 to 3).toList).myApply(_.toString + "*", ith = 2)
res: List[Any] = List(1, 2*, 3)
```

---

Edit: Fixed it!

```
implicit class Seq_[A, Repr](seq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) {
  def myApply[B >: A, That](f: A => B, ith: Int)
                           (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

Example:

```
scala> (1 to 3).toList.myApply(_ + 10, ith = 2)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)

scala> (1 to 3).toVector.myApply(Math.pow(2, _), ith = 3)
res: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[AnyVal] = Vector(1, 2, 8.0)
```

---

But I just realized you also wanted it to work for `Array`, which isn't `SeqLike`, so let me think some more...

Ah, `Predef` has an implicit conversion from `Array` to `ArrayOps`, which is a subtype of `SeqLike`, so we just need to use a view bound.

```
implicit class Seq_[A, Repr <% SeqLike[A, Repr]](seq: Repr) {
  def myApply[B >: A, That](f: A => B, ith: Int)
                           (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

And finally we have the right behavior:

```
scala> (1 to 3).toList.myApply(_ + 10, ith = 2)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)

scala> (1 to 3).toArray.myApply(Math.pow(2, _), ith = 3)
res: Array[AnyVal] = Array(1, 2, 8.0)
```

---

Edit again - samthebest informs me that view bounds are deprecated, so using [this guide](http://jatin.x10.mx/2014/03/replace-view-bounds/) we can replace it with a very ugly-looking context bound.

```
implicit class Seq_[A, Repr, 
    S : ({type L[X] = X => SeqLike[A, Repr]})#L](seq: S) {

  def myApply[B >: A, That](f: A => B, ith: Int)
      (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    seq.updated(ith - 1, f(seq(ith - 1)))
}
```

Comment: A "seed" upvote hoping you'll work out the type args. It's so easy to burn an hour on collections.

Comment: When it comes to implicits that don't apply, I can never tell whether it's my bug or the compiler's, so it's hard to know when to call it quits.

Comment: Fixed, although I still don't know why.

Comment: Nice, but I won't reward with upvote until you refactor to use Context Bounds given View Bounds are deprecated :)

Comment: Hm, I didn't know view bounds were deprecated. `scala.collection` doesn't contain an appropriate type class for this, does it? Why does `Array` have to be such a pariah? :(

Answer (score 3):

Someone just asked about patch, so maybe this is a duplicate:

```
scala> val list = (1 to 3).toList
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> def f(v: Int): Int = v + 10
f: (v: Int)Int

scala> def g(is: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int) = is.patch(i, Seq(f(is(i))), 1)
g: (is: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int)Seq[Int]

scala> g(list, f, 1)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)
```

Generalizing a smidgen:

```
scala> def g(is: collection.Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int, count: Int = 1) = is.patch(i, is.slice(i, i + count) map f, count)
g: (is: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int, count: Int)Seq[Int]

scala> g(list, f, 1)
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 12, 3)

scala> g(list, f, 1, 2)
res3: Seq[Int] = List(1, 12, 13)
```

This was my first go, as Chris prompts:

```
scala> def g(is: collection.mutable.Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int) = is(i) = f(is(i))
g: (is: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int)Unit

scala> val as = (1 to 10).toArray
as: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> g(as, f, 1)

scala> as
res7: Array[Int] = Array(1, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

So as Chris was saying:

```
scala> def g(is: collection.Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int) = is.updated(i, f(is(i)))
g: (is: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, i: Int)Seq[Int]
```

And good night, Gracie.

Answer (score 0):

It is very complex to add additional methods to the existing collections with implicits. If using an external method OK, this is a solution. 
Almost there but not quite. Example in a Scala IDE worksheet

```
object SeqOps {
  def applyToith(col: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, ith: Int): Seq[Int] = {
    val indexCol = col.zipWithIndex
    indexCol.map {
      a => if (a._2 == ith) f(a._1) else a._1
    }
  }                                       //> applyToith: (col: Seq[Int], f: Int => Int, ith: Int)Seq[Int]

  def f(i: Int) = i + 10                  //> f: (i: Int)Int
  val l = List(1, 2, 3)                   //> l  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
  applyToith(l, f _, 0)                   //> res0: Seq[Int] = List(11, 2, 3)

  val a = Array(1, 2, 3)                  //> a  : Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
  applyToith(a, f _, 1)                   //> res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 12, 3)

  val v = Vector(1, 2, 3)                 //> v  : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
  applyToith(v, f _, 2)                   //> res2: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 13)

}
```

In the case of an array, it returns an ArrayBuffer instead of Array. For all other Seq types works properly. I have tried many other combinations but nothing fixes this issue.

```
val a : Seq[Int] = Array(1, 2)
a.zipWithIndex
```

This zipWithIndex returns an ArrayBuffer but if `val a: Array[Int]` is used, `zipWithIndex` returns an Array.

The vagaries of retro-fitting Java arrays into collections I guess.