# Flattening a map of sets

Tags: scala

I am trying to flatten a map where the keys are traversables, in the sense that:

```
Map( Set(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Set(4, 5, 6) -> 'B')
```

should flatten to:

```
Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)
```

Here is what I did:

```
def fuse[A, B, T <: Traversable[A]](mapOfTravs: Map[T, B]): Map[A, B] = {
  val pairs = for {
    trav <- mapOfTravs.keys
    key <- trav
  } yield (key, mapOfTravs(trav))
  pairs.toMap
}
```

It works.  But:

1. Is there a simpler way to do this?
2. I'm not very comfortable with the Scala type system and I'm sure this can be improved.  I have to specify the types explicitly whenever I use my function:

   ```
   val map2 = Map( Set(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Set(4, 5, 6) -> 'B')
   val fused2 = fuse[Int, Char, Set[Int]](map2)

   val map1: Map[Traversable[Int], Char] = Map( Set(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Set(4, 5, 6) -> 'B')
   val fused1 = fuse[Int, Char, Traversable[Int]](map1)
   ```

P.S.: this `fuse` function does not make much sense when the key traversables have a non-null intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Azzie, I was thinking zip, but maybe Azzie has the advantage with those zees.

```
scala> val m = Map( Set(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Set(4, 5, 6) -> 'B')
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int],Char] = Map(Set(1, 2, 3) -> A, Set(4, 5, 6) -> B)

scala> (m map { case (k, v) => k zip (Stream continually v) }).flatten.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Char] = Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)

scala> (m map { case (k, v) => k zipAll (Nil, null, v) }).flatten.toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Char] = Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)

scala> m flatMap { case (k, v) => k zip (Stream continually v) }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Char] = Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)
```

It's not obvious how to generalize it nicely.

Comment: I keep forgetting about streams. Do they have any overhead to be concerned about?

Answer (score 4):

This is basically what you're doing in the for comprehension, but simplified a little bit:

```
  def fuse[A, B, T <: Traversable[A]](mapOfTravs: Map[T, B]): Map[A, B] = {
    mapOfTravs.flatMap({ case (s, c) => s.map(i => i -> c) })
  }
```

Not much you can do about the types, I'm sure there's some type lambda shenanigans that you can do, I'm just not sure how to do them...

**UPDATE**
Here's a slightly better for version, same as the above flatMap:

```
  def fuse2[A, B, T <: Traversable[A]](mapOfTravs: Map[T, B]): Map[A, B] = {
    for {
      (keys, value) <- mapOfTravs
      key <- keys
    } yield key -> value
  }
```

Comment: I actually had this form, but I changed it to a `for`-comprehension before posting it here since it's more readable.  Whenever I see a `flatMap(map())` I convert it to a `for`-comprehension.

Comment: @toto2 Put an update in with a better version of the for comprehension, your's was calling back into the map etc when it didn't really need to

Answer (score 1):

This looks horrible and using 0 is kind of cheating but it does the job

```
 m.map( {case (s,c) => s.zipAll(Set(c),0,c)} ).flatten.toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm apparently on a "hideously generic implicits" kick [lately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800702/apply-function-to-one-element-only-in-list-or-array-in-scala/25801125#25801125):

```
import scala.collection.MapLike
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class Map_[
  A,
  B,
  T1 : ({type L[X] = X => TraversableLike[A, T2]})#L,
  T2,
  M1 : ({type L[X] = X => MapLike[T1, B, M2]})#L, 
  M2 <: MapLike[T1, B, M2] with Map[T1, B]
](map: M1) {

  def fuse[M3](implicit cbfM: CanBuildFrom[M2, (A, B), M3]) : M3 =
    map.flatMap({ case (k, v) => k.toTraversable.map((_, v)) })
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> Map(Set(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Set(4, 5, 6) -> 'B').fuse
res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Char] =
     Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)

scala> Map(Array(1, 2, 3) -> 'A', Array(4, 5, 6) -> 'B').fuse
res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Char] =
     Map(5 -> B, 1 -> A, 6 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> A, 4 -> B)
```